# boostrap 4 carousel и backface-visibility

Tags: css, bootstrap, carousel

День добрый. Есть такая проблема: сайт http://roskapstroy.ru на бустрап 4, и в нем есть функция для слабовидящих. Этот блок скрыт и появляется при нажатии на [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и далее можно выбрать парметры для отображения текста, который устанавливает свойство filter для трех блоков-оберток контента страницы. Но есть момент, при установке двух любых параметров(шрифт, яркость, контрастность и тд), почему то слайдер на главной странице начинает лагать и пропадает весь контент. Выяснил что это из за [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это можно пофиксить? Причем в Firefox все нормально работает, а в Chrome нет

Comment: причем на https://akdgs.ru/ - тот же скрипт, но сайт сам на бустрап 3 и там нормально все

Comment: Никто не знает?